# What happened to a question I asked? Did it get deleted? Migrated?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972841/testflight-external-testers-upgrade-workflow-after-app-is-released-to-app-store) I asked vanished from the Questions tab in my SO profile. Where did it go?  I looked through the deletion tab in my profile and I didn't see any indication that I deleted it. (although before making this meta post I did find an old bad question I asked, and deleted that one!)

Anyway, if my recent question was deleted by moderation tools or moderators, is it expected that it's deleted from my profile too?

If it was migrated to another StackExchange site, will be there be a notification in my SO profile that this happened?

The question had no answers and a downvote or two when I last looked at it. So it's not like I'd blame an automated or human moderation process for hiding my question from everyone else. But hiding it from me seems like taking moderation a bit too far.

**EDIT:** Thanks [@bluefeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) for finding the URL of my missing question!

Comment: [This question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972841/testflight-external-testers-upgrade-workflow-after-app-is-released-to-app-store)

Comment: BTW: Profile page -> Question Tab -> Recently deleted should list that question...

Comment: As you already know, your question has been cleaned up automatically. However, I'd have voted to close it as too broad, or primarily opinion based. It doesn't look a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: As much as I'm keen to close discursive questions, I think it's an edge-case that would be interesting to have, and it is saved by thorough prior research. I've voted to undelete.

Comment: Looks like it was just undeleted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So as I alluded to earlier, this looks like it was [automatically cleaned up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/175248).  Here's the criteria your question fell under:

> The system will automatically [delete unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/175248).

To be explicit about that specific rule:

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> **...or...**
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.