# Looking for MY questions (questions I have asked)

Tags: support

I finally (after months of fiddeling around) figured out a solution to a problem I'm pretty sure I posted here on Stack Overflow and I'd like to mark the question as answered, but I can find my question.

Is there anyway for me to list all the questions I have asked?

Comment: Search for [`user:me is:q`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq)

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286929/what-happened-to-a-question-i-asked-did-it-get-deleted-migrated

Comment: It is weird that when you go to your profile and click on quenstions you don't get a list of your questions but someone elses. Or not all of them or someone deleted my question (what a jerk).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Go to your Profile -> Questions and you will see all the questions.

or

Here is link to all your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions

Comment: what if i want to list out the questions with a specific tag example "svg"

Comment: Seems the list is not complete. I can't find my questions with negative scores on the list. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5318303/mir-ismaili?tab=questions) is the list of my questions and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733312/where-is-jre-11) is the link of one special question with negative score (till now).

Answer (score 5):

Go to your profile (link on the upper black header of the site), click on questions, search for your question, click on it and mark the specific answer as correct.