# How can I find all questions I have asked with a certain tag?

Tags: support, search

I would like to find all questions that I have asked with a specific tag, e.g. [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

I have read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313548/looking-for-my-questions-questions-i-have-asked/313549#313549), it gives a way to search for your own questions but without a tag.

How do I go on about this?

Comment: You can use the [search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), or use my [search helper userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011) to put it together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do a simple search:

[user:me is:q [android]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20is%3Aq%20[android])